# syntax error when running query in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

good day

i am trying to run an update query but getting the following error "syntax error in join operation"
Here is the query:

```
update (table 1 

set SEQ=table2.SEQ) 

from (table1 inner join table2 on table1.NBR=table2.NBR and table1.LINE = table2.LINE and table1.VENNO = table2.VENNO and table1.INVNO = table2.INVNO where table1.SEQ <> table2.seq)
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. `UPDATE` queries don't use `FROM`. The right syntax is:

```
update 
    table1
    inner join table2 
        on table1.NBR=table2.NBR 
           and table1.LINE = table2.LINE 
           and table1.VENNO = table2.VENNO 
           and table1.INVNO = table2.INVNO
 set
     table1.SEQ = table2.SEQ
 where 
     table1.SEQ <> table2.seq
```